# mysql treat fields containing letters as lowest value when sorting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column (x) that contains both numbers letters. When I use

```
ORDER BY x DESC
```

It puts the fields containing letters at the top. How can I make it treat fields containing letters as the lowest value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a case statement in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when left(x, 1) between '0' and '9' then 0 else 1 end),
         x desc
```

EDIT:

If you want fields that contain *a* letter at the top:

```
order by (case when x like '%[a-zA-Z]%' then 0 else 1 end),
         x desc;
```

If you want fields that contain *only* letters at the top:

```
order by (case when x not like '%[^a-zA-Z]%' then 0 else 1 end),
         x desc;
```

If you want fields that *only* contain numbers at the bottom:

```
order by (case when x not like '%[^0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end),
         x desc;
```

Comment: I don't think so.  The question is about values that contain letters.  This answer deals with values that start with a non-numeric character.

Comment: @DanBracuk . . . Without sample data, the question is ambiguous.  I revised my answer.

Comment: I'll assume that MySQL supports the syntax in your revision.  I don't actually know.  I have removed my down vote.

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY x+0 DESC - that should work

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option would be `ORDER BY LEFT('0' + x, 2) DESC`. This would ensure that `0 - 9` were zero padded and thus make the character value `01` less then `10`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Table1 order by 
CAST(x AS UNSIGNED),x;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70d00/4)